# Socket IO works fine on local machine but doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

**Situation:**

I'm building an web app (a SPA) with ReactJS and ExpressJS. I'm using Socket.IO for real-time chatting. When I build my app and run it on localhost, everything works fine so I decide to deploy it on Heroku. My app is built successfully on Heroku and ready to use.

**Problem:**

So I enter my app to see if it works fine on Heroku. The app seems to be ok when I enter login page and register page (these pages are not going with Socket.IO). But when I go to chat page (this page is using Socket.IO for real-time chatting), the client is crashed, it's not loaded and throw the below error.

**Error:**

I get this following error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DEBUG' of undefined
    at load (browser.js:168)
    at Object.eval (browser.js:178)
    at eval (browser.js:197)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/debug/src/browser.js (vendor.js:2639)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:788)
    at fn (main.js:151)
    at eval (url.js:7)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/url.js (vendor.js:2628)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:788)
    at fn (main.js:151)
```

When I look at the module online, it has the following check:

```
// If debug isn't set in LS, and we're in Electron, try to load $DEBUG
  if (!r && typeof process !== 'undefined' && 'env' in process) {
    r = undefined.DEBUG; //the error is showed here
  }
```

So I start my app on localhost and search for above code, I get this:

```
// If debug isn't set in LS, and we're in Electron, try to load $DEBUG
  if (!r && typeof process !== 'undefined' && 'env' in process) {
    r = { /*A JSON object contains .env variables*/ }.DEBUG;
  }
```

**Code:**

This is my server:

```
//requirements...
const socket = require("./server/socket");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//middlewares...
//routes...
//database connection...

socket(server);

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server started on: " + port);
```

My socket setup:

```
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const socket = server => {
    const io = socketIO(server);
    const chat = io.of("/chat");

    chat.on("connection", client => {
        console.log("User started chat!");

        client.on("disconnect", () => {
            console.log("User left chat!");
        });

        client.on("sendMessage", msg => {
            const data = msg;
            client.broadcast.emit("incomingMessage", { data });
        });
    });
};

module.exports = socket;
```

React component that using Socket.IO:

```
const _ChatBox = ({ props }) => {
    const [connection] = useState(io("/chat"));

    useEffect(() => {
        connection.on("incomingMessage", message => {
            //receive message...
        });
    }, []);

    const sendMessageToSocket = data => {
        connection.emit("sendMessage", data);
    };

    return (
        /* JSX here */
    );
};
```

**What I want:**

I want to know if there is any problem with my code. When I deploy my app to Heroku, is there any extra setup I have to do on Heroku to make my app working with Socket.IO?

Comment: What is crashing? The server or the client?

Comment: @VaughanHilts the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours researching and reviewing my code, I have figured out why my app is not working on Heroku. That because the client using `dotenv` module, and I setup it in `webpack.config.js`:

```
//...requirements
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    //...configs
    plugins: [
        //...other plugins
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)
        })
    ]
};
```

Then when I deploy my app on Heroku, Heroku will build my client from source code and server will look for the frontend part in `dist` folder. The client now can't find the `.env` file on Heroku so it can't load the environment variables that causes it to throw error.

I removed `dotenv` because I don't need it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you have pasted, or at least I doubt it. If you look at the module online, you see it has the following check:

```
    // If debug isn't set in LS, and we're in Electron, try to load $DEBUG
    if (!r && typeof process !== 'undefined' && 'env' in process) {
        r = process.env.DEBUG;
    }
```

You will notice it's reading it off `process.env`, this is a Node thing / Electron thing. Inside of the console of your client, type `window.process`, if you get something, that's probably it. It's inspecting `process`... probably webpack

Comment: I get this `r = undifined.DEBUG;` instead `r = process.env.DEBUG;`

Comment: For `window.process`?

Comment: yes, when I type `window.process`, it returns `undefined`